# Need help in php array to json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Having an array

```
`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [operative] => 2
            [start] =>  01:00:00
            [end] =>  13:00:00
            [color] => 543939
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [operative] => 3
            [start] =>  08:00:00
            [end] =>  09:00:00
            [color] => 52e612
        )

)

`
```

need to change this into JSON so I use json_encode(), I get a string 
`[{"operative":"2","start":" 01:00:00","end":" 13:00:00","color":"543939"},{"operative":"3","start":" 08:00:00","end":" 09:00:00","color":"52e612"}]`

but when I am using JSON into JavaScript by function $.parseJSON() or JSON.parse(), both are giving me not defined.

ok I have used it like this

```
options1 = '[{"operative":"2","start":" 01:00:00","end":" 13:00:00","color":"543939"},{"operative":"3","start":" 08:00:00","end":" 09:00:00","color":"52e612"}]'
options1 = $.parseJSON(options1);
alert($.param(options1));
```

But alert is showing me undefined=&undefined=

Comment: give us your javascript code.

Comment: did you surround it by quotes?

Comment: Make sure that the data you retrieve is, in fact, the json string and nothing more than that (`console.log()` it). Your json itself is valid, so `$.parseJSON( data )` should return an array if you are passing that string as an argument.

Comment: `var data = <?= json_encode($data) ?>;`

Comment: I don't think alert takes 2 parameters

Comment: Drop the quotes, and don't parsre, and you're home and dry. Check my answer for details

Comment: ok thaks all it simply works like this and I get my values, I am on wrong track $(options1).each(function(i,n){  alert(n.end);
 });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're echo-ing that json encoded string into your javascript. You can do this, and just leave the quotes out:

```
var options = <?= json_encode($array); ?>;
```

JSON is an acronym for JavaScript Object Notation. Echoing it into a JS script results in valid javascript arrays and object literals. No need to parse it at all.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using  $.parseJSON() -function, the parseable data should be string:

```
var json = '[{"operative":"2","start":" 01:00:00","end":" 13:00:00","color":"543939"},{"operative":"3","start":" 08:00:00","end":" 09:00:00","color":"52e612"}]';

console.log($.parseJSON(json));
```

Answer (score 1):

Until you show your code I am assuming that this is what you did:

```
var object = $.parseJSON(<?php echo json_encode($array)?>);
```

and this wont work because `parseJSON` expects a string as a parameter.

so the solution will be:

```
var object = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($array)?>');
```

Note that it is surrounded by quotes.

Comment: But... why parse it if JSON is actually a JavaScript code?
Just do `var data = <?= json_encode($data) ?>;`, no parsing needed!

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse() expects the argument to be a string. Make your JSON data a string by surrounding it with 'single-quotes' (because you've used "double quotes" inside the JSON already)

Comment: Or leave the quotes, and don't parse _valid JSON_. JavaScript Object Notation is valid JavaScript, just echo it unquoted!

Answer (score 0):

Use [parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

```
done(function (jsonresponse) {
var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonresponse);        
console.log(obj);
};
```